# Deploy Kubernetes on AWS Reserved instances

Tags: kops

I'm very new to KOPS, so I have very questions about the cluster deployment process in AWS.

Supose I have 3 reserved instances: I want to deploy one Master and two workers in my existing AWS reserved instances.

Can anyone write a step by step guide to acomplsih that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the cluster you must specify the node and master types to match those of the reserved instances, using the arguments `--master-size` and `--node-size`. For example if you have reserved m4.large instances just set `--master-size=m4.large`.

If the instance type you're using is the same as the reserved one, AWS will apply the discount automatically.

Comment: Make sure the reservation scope is region(which would only give you the price benefits). If the reservation scope is Availability Zone make sure the cluster is launched in particular AZ. AZ reservations gives you cost benefits and capacity assurance. zone can be specified using --zones option.